# In InfluxDB: I am unable to convert an expression to an integer

Tags: grafana, influxdb

The intention is that `Grafana 6.6.1` will query this from `InfluxDb 1.8.2`

I want to use the [moving_average()](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/functions/#moving-average) function based on the time period `$timeFilter` that is selected in the dashboard.

I have tried a few queries in the CLI. In the following snippets, `time > '2020-10-27'` will be substituted by `$timeFilter` in Grafana.

query 1:

```SQL
SELECT  round(count("Temp")*0.1)  FROM "Consumption" WHERE time > '2020-10-27'
```

Outputs:

```
name: Consumption
time                           round
----                           -----
2020-10-27T00:00:00.000000001Z 7
```

query 2:

```SQL
SELECT moving_average("Temp", 7) FROM "Consumption" WHERE time > '2020-10-27'
```

Outputs:

```
name: Consumption
time                 moving_average
----                 --------------
2020-11-03T00:00:00Z 7.535714285714286
2020-11-04T00:00:00Z 7.184528571428571
2020-11-05T00:00:00Z 6.833342857142857
2020-11-06T00:00:00Z 7.303585714285714
.....etc
```

However, I am unable to combine these queries

query 3:

```SQL
SELECT moving_average("Temp", round(count("Temp")*0.1)) FROM "Consumption" WHERE time > '2020-10-27'
```

Outputs:

```
ERR: second argument for moving_average must be an integer, got *influxql.Call
```

So I guess `round()` does  not return an integer. Any advice on how to solve this?

---

### Edit

bonus question: How do I make sure the second argument in `moving_average()` never goes below 1. If selecting a shorter timespan, then it shall be 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I got it working now.

In Grafana I added a variable to the dashboard.

### Variables

`Name: MyRollingAvgValue`, `Type: Query`, `Hide: Variable`, `Refrech: on time range change`

And the query itself for the variable:

```SQL
SELECT mean(MyVal::integer) As MyRollingAvg FROM 
( SELECT 1+round(count("Temp")*0.1) as MyVal FROM "Consumption" WHERE $timeFilter )
```

---

### Panel in the dashboard

**Querys tab**

```SQL
SELECT moving_average("Temp", $MyRollingAvgValue) FROM "Consumption" WHERE $timeFilter
```

`ALIAS BY: °C ($MyRollingAvgValue day avg)`

**Visualization tab**

- `Add series override`

`alias or regex` --> `/.*day avg/`